# convert sh script that uses docker to bat script

Tags: docker, batch-file, redis, sh

I have the following SH file:

```
#------------ bootstrap the cluster nodes --------------------

start_cmd='redis-server --port 6379 --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config- 
file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000 --appendonly yes'
redis_image='redis:5.0.3'
network_name='redis_cluster_net'

docker network create $network_name
echo $network_name " created"

#---------- create the cluster ------------------------

for port in `seq 6379 6384`; do \
 docker run -d --name "redis-"$port -p $port:6379 --net $network_name 
$redis_image $start_cmd;
 echo "created redis cluster node redis-"$port
done

cluster_hosts=''

for port in `seq 6379 6384`; do \
 hostip=`docker inspect -f '{{(index .NetworkSettings.Networks 
"redis_cluster_net").IPAddress}}' "redis-"$port`;
 echo "IP for cluster node redis-"$port "is" $hostip
 cluster_hosts="$cluster_hosts$hostip:6379 ";
done

echo "cluster hosts "$cluster_hosts
echo "creating cluster...."
echo 'yes' | docker run -i --rm --net $network_name $redis_image redis-cli --cluster create $cluster_hosts --cluster-replicas 1;
```

I attempted to convert this into a bat file but its my first time really trying and the file below doesn't seem to work "Invalid address format: "' was unexpected at this time."

I'm guessing there may be some other mistakes.

Could anyone help spot them so i can make the change?

```
@echo off

REM bootstrap the cluster nodes

SET start_cmd="redis-server --port 6379 --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.conf --cluster-node-timeout 5000 --appendonly yes"
SET redis_image="redis:5.0.3"
SET network_named="redis_cluster_net"

docker network create %network_named%
echo %network_name% " created"

REM Create the cluster

for /l %%i in (6379, 1, 6384) do ( 
    docker run -d --name redis-%%i -p %%i:6379 --net %network_named% %redis_image% %start_cmd%;
    echo created redis cluster node redis-%%i
)

SET cluster_hosts=""

for /l %%j in (6379, 1, 6384) do (
    SET hostip="docker inspect -f '{{(index .NetworkSettings.Networks ""redis_cluster_net"").IPAddress}}' redis-%%j"
    echo IP for cluster node redis-%%j is %hostip%
    SET cluster_hosts= "%cluster_hosts% %hosthip% :6379 "
)

echo "cluster hosts " %cluster_hosts%
echo "creating cluster...."
docker run -i --rm --net %network_named%  %redis_image% redis-cli --cluster create  %cluster_hosts%  --cluster-replicas 1;
```

Comment: ok, so we use single characters for token variables `%%i` and not words like `%%ports` also, `for /l` counter requires `(n,n,n)` counting `(from, in sets of, up to)` we do not use single quotes to set anythig, and we wrap the set variable in double quotes, including the variable name.. i.e `SET "start_cmd=redis-server --port 6379......"` We also `echo` created variables wrapped in `%` i.e `echo %network_name% created`

Comment: @MostafaHussein not even close, the variable was never set, even if it was, we would have `%` both sides, not one side, and `delayedexpansion` we replace `%` with `!`

Comment: @MostafaHussein yes, so I am aware you are trying to help, but let's research before we post something that makes no sense :)

Comment: thanks for the tips sorted it out still getting issues with the docker run inside the loop

Comment: You will. There is still alot weong with the code. Post ammended code let us see..

Comment: updated it, seems me trying to reference the token %%i value into redis_%i%

Comment: No. You never created a variable called `%j%` it must be `%%j` also `cluster_hosts hosthip`? You should add actual values here.

Comment: updated script and the error almost there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189886/discussion-between-lemunk-and-gerhard-barnard).